# Recover data from locked iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, backup, data-recovery, unlock

Here's the deal... I've an ipad that is locked after missing the lock key a few times.

Now it is requesting to connect to iTunes but this iPad was never synced with the iTunes. I know i can restore to factory settings but I don't want to lose everything.

Is there anyway to unlock the iPad without loosing all the data that is inside? Or retrieve the data from it in some way? I don't have any backup...

The iPad is running iOS 7.

It is very important that I can get the photos that are inside.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough question even for law enforcement. There's some software out there that claims to do this, try Google. You can also jailbreak older devices but you don't say what kind of iPad you have.

http://www.redsn0w.us/2010/03/download-direct-links-jailbreak-guides.html

Try recovery mode if you don't have iTunes, at least you can use the iPad after.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1212